# Extends Spring security user class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm Working on a Spring security project . I try to extends the  security.core.userdetails.User class to add more details while registering the users.

**User Extended class**

```
public class UserDetails extends User {

    private int id;
    private String Country;


public UserDetails(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, int id,
        String country) {
    super(username, password, authorities);
    this.id = id;
    Country = country;
}

public UserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
        boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,
        int id, String country) {
    super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    this.id = id;
    Country = country;
}




public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}


public void setCountry(String country) {
    Country = country;
}
```

I have also added Id and country in my entity class(model class).

But when i try to register the user .
It give an error.**org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into users (username, password, enabled) values (?,?,?)]; Field 'id' doesn't have a default value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value**

(The value of id and country is hard coded)

**Controller class**

```
try {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authority = new ArrayList<>();
        authority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(form.getRole()));
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(form.getPassword());
        
        UserDetails details = new UserDetails(form.getUsername(), encodedPassword, authority, 10 ,"India");
        System.out.println(details.getId()+" "+details.getCountry() +" "+details.getUsername());
        System.out.println(details);
        detailsManager.createUser(details);
  }
```

***OUPUT***

10 India alpha@gmail.com

com.example.demo.model.UserDetails [Username=alpha@gmail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]

I don't know why its is calling the parent class constructor.

Comment: could you add User class definition?

Comment: User is spring security User class( org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is incorrect. Spring Security's `INSERT` by default populates the `username`, `password`, and `enabled` columns. However, the `users` table you created requires an `id` column as well. Since the query doesn't specify the value, it fails.

You could try extending `JdbcUserDetailsManager`'s various methods to be aware of your `id` field as well. You'd need to at least extend `createUser` so it adds the `id` to the `INSERT` statement and `findUserByUsername` so it constructs your custom object.

A better way, though, would be to [use Spring Data](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/java8). This allows your domain object to be independent of Spring Security. Also, Spring Data has much broader SQL support.

It might be helpful to call your class something different than a Spring Security interface. So, let's imagine that your custom class (the one with the `id`) is called `YourUser` (instead of `UserDetails`). Now, you can wire a Spring Data-based `UserDetailsService` to Spring Security like so:

```java
@Service
public class YourUserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final YourUserRepository users; // your Spring Data repository

    // ... constructor

    @Override
    public UserDetails findUserByUsername(String username) {
        YourUser user = this.users.findByUsername(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("not found"));
        return new UserDetailsAdapter(user);
    }

    private static class UserDetailsAdapter extends YourUser implements UserDetails {
        UserDetailsAdapter(YourUser user) {
            super(user); // copy constructor
        }

        // ... implement UserDetails methods
    }
}
```

This `UserDetailsService` replaces the `JdbcUserDetailsManager` that you are publishing.

Comment: HI thanks for the reply , but i didn't  get that  part ie creating a service class of User Details. Basically user details class  is an extension of User class( org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User).

Comment: I changed the class names and added a bit more explanation. Does that help?